# How to export "descriptions of variables" below variable names from R to csv or excel format?

Tags: r, export-to-csv

[Sample view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crJm9.png)I imported a .dta file into R using foreign package and now I want to export the same file into a csv or excel format. The table has 23415 ops. and  5588 variables. Each of these variables have a description beneath them in the same row as I view it in R.

When I export the data frame into a csv or excel format, the variables are well exported but the descriptions of the variables are missing.

I want the table as it is in excel which would show the data set with the column variables and the descriptions as the first row, as I view it in R Studio. Can anyone advise as I've tried other solutions but it is not working.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi can you share some data via ```dput()``` will be helpful to help.

Comment: Hi Tushar, thanks for your response. I tried to run dput() but it does not give me the required output. I'm new to R so you might have to elaborate this for me which will be more useful for me as a beginner.

Comment: to share sample data just do example ```dput(mtcars) ```  in console R studio where here mtcars is data frame.if you want to just save data then ```write.csv(df,'df.csv',rows.names=F) ```

Comment: I ran it couple of times but R studio keeps restarting. Have shared an image above. Hope that helps

Comment: write.csv(df,'df.csv',rows.names=F) this works but descriptions of variables are still missing.

Comment: i think you have large data frame.just create sample data frame and sample output.you want to save the file in .csv or excel as it is available in data.frame is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yup, its meta data. I  have converted it into a data frame. Is there a way I can only export variables and their descriptions without the data?

Comment: Hi ,then you can just do ```colnames(df)``` hope this will help or you can do if you want some row then ```df1 <- df[1,]```